# Answer acceptance from previous day changes limit of today

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

I have had a couple of instances where an answer accepted from a previous day, changes the total limit I can achieve today. The OP changes the acceptance, brievely, but then the re-acceptance still registers 15 points for today

Obviously this only reduces my total for the day by 15, but i would like to know why this is?

Is there no way to say, well i have already accepted this persons answer, so if i do reaccept it, it will not change that days total?

Hope I explained it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That makes sense to me. If a user accepts an answer *today*, you receive the points today, regardless of when the question was asked (or originally accepted). It works the same as votes placed on any post. You receive the points the day the vote is cast (even if it is retracted and then re-added later).

What I *don't* fully understand is why accepted-answer points are applied to the daily limit the way they do. This has been discussed extensively. *Personally, I stopped worrying about it a long time ago.*

- If your answer is accepted *after* you reached the daily limit, you *still* get the points (those points **are exempt** from the daily limit).
- If your answer is accepted *before* you reached the daily limit, they are counted towards the daily limit (those points **are not exempt** from the daily limit).

If accepted answers are exempt from the daily limit, why not make them exempt?

```
if (votingPoints > DailyCap)
{
    votingPoints = DailyCap;
}
totalPoints = votingPoints + exemptPoints;
```

Comment: Hmm... not basic... not python... obviously not C, perl, java, JS, etc...

Comment: Ha! It was pseudo-pseudo code. I *thought* I was on meta.StackExchange so I was making it non-programming, English-like. I fixed the "code sample" to be more palatable for the programming crowd.

Comment: sorry, make an edit so i can upvote

Answer (score 3):

Don't stress so much over the number. Yes this happens, yes people have suggested (for example) that accepted answers are counted differently; no nothing has changed. I wouldn't worry about it - it isn't the most important thing. Just keep adding great answers ;-p